# are Print Statements inside or outside of For Loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, printing

I'm coding a program to calculate factorials but can't seem to figure out the part where it actually prints out the final value.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Factorial {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter integer value: ");
    int x=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(x+"!=");
    int y=0;


    for(int i=x;i>0;i--) {
        //y=x*i;
        y=i*(i-1);

         if(i==1) 
        System.out.print(i+"=");

        else
            System.out.print(i+"*");
        //for (int j=2;j>=1

    }
    System.out.print(y);        
}
}
```

the program is supposed to display the numbers it multiplied by as well

> i.e. INPUT=5
>   OUTPUT= 5!=5*4*3*2*1=120
>   or
>   OUTPUT=5!=1*2*3*4*5=120

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is to put the curly brackets on and then indent,so as to decrease the confusion.
The code below does what you intend to and has the necessary comments

```
import java.util.*;

public class Factorial {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter integer value: ");
    int x=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print(x+"!=");
    int y=1;// Initialize to 1 not 0 as you'll be multiplying.


    for(int i=x;i>0;i--) {

        /*
          Iteration by iteration:
          i = 5,y= 1-> y = 1*5
          i = 4,y= 5-> y = 5*4
          So on...
        */
        y*=(i);

         if(i==1) 
            {
                // Print Equal only if its the last number. Since 
                   we are going 5*4*3*2*1 =. We need this if to print
                   1 =.
                System.out.print(i+"=");

            }

        else
            {
                //For other cases just print Number and *.
                System.out.print(i+"*");

            }


    }
    // Print the actual output.
    System.out.print(y);        



}

}
```